# Mailhog, Trapmailer and gmail via symfony

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, mailtrap, mailhog

I got some trouble with mails generation on my Symfony app :

I use docker
when I use Gmail to send emails :

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://MyAddress@gmail.com:MyPw@localhost
```

everything works fine

but as soon as I try to intercept these mails :

======================

Like this for mailtrap

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://b3f077aeceaeb6:8792a1811dd8ef@smtp.mailtrap.io:2525?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.mailtrap.io:25&auth_mode=login&username=b3f077aeceaeb6&password=8792a1811dd8ef
```

or like this for mailHog

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost:1025
MAILER_URL="smtp://mailhog:1025?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=null&password=null"
```

my docker-compose.yml looks like this :

```yaml
mailhog:
    container_name: mailhog
    restart: always
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest

    ports:
        -'8025:8025'
        -'1025:1025'
```

Does anyone know how to see the mails displayed in mailhog? mailhog page is loaded correctly but nothing shows in it.
The function sending the mail is entered, so this must be a configuration problem in my opinion

Comment: Please share more details about the error you are facing

Comment: i can't see if the emails are sent, and i don't see no emails in mailhog :)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Why not use Symfony's developer toolbar to check for errors?

Comment: Also, how are the containers linked? You've only shared the configuration of a single mailhog container

Comment: hmmmm i don't really know about the docker linking, i'm not very confortable with docker :s

Comment: Then please share more details, for example the configuration for the container running your application

Answer (score 3):

Based on your post, I had a similar problem with mailhog and SwiftMailer for Symfony.

I ended up using the smtp for both `MAILER_DSN` and `MAILER_URL` as follows

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost:1025
MAILER_URL="smtp://localhost:1025?auth_mode=login"
```

As you can see the trick was to remove `encryption=ssl` as the mailhog does not supports it and the `username=null&password=null` as the software sends it as literal string `"null"`.

Besides, in my `swiftmailer.yaml` and `mailer.yaml` I have this very simple configuration

```
# swiftmailer.yaml
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

---

```
# mailer.yaml
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

Comment: Just `MAILER_DSN` seems to be enough.

Answer (score -3):

You need to narrow down the issue.

**1. Can you send you an email via `telnet` or `openssl` (in case of STARTTLS)?**

Via telnet: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404584/sending-or-viewing-emails-using-telnet

Via OpenSSL: https://www.stevenrombauts.be/2018/12/test-smtp-with-telnet-or-openssl/

Go through the tutorial (or any on this topic) and make sure your MAILER_URL is correct (including credentials, port, etc). The last time I had some issue with email, turned out that the firewall was blocking me.

Don't be quick to rule out networking issues.

**2. Once you confirmed that you can send an email via Telnet/OpenSSL:**

you need to go level up and try to configure the URL in Symfony and attempt sending via `swiftmailer:send` command. This may reveal some odd configuration issues in Symfony and you can fix them accordingly

**3. Repeat (1) and (2) but from Docker container.**

Just `exec` into Docker and do it all over again. This may reveal some issues in Docker network configuration, which you can fix.

Please update your question with more findings and we could probably help you further...